# Why does Yona build a non-kosher succah?

Tags: sukkah, yonah-jonah-book-of, architecture-design

In Yona 4:8 why does Yona build a succa that allows more sun than shade?

Comment: It probably wasn't Sukos.

Comment: @ba, +1 on your comment, but the question remains: if he built it for shade, why not make it properly? OTOH, I don't see any evidence in the question that he actually built it with more sun than shade (or built it at all): −1.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest ?

Comment: It certainly wasn't kosher because the kikayon was alive and attached to the ground. That said, I don't see why you would expect him to build a kosher sukkah.

Answer (score 7):

The [Posuk](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=193) does not say that there was more sun than shade. On the contrary the Posuk says "Vayeshev Tacteho Bzel" which translates into "He sat under it in the shade.

The following Posuk says that a Kikoyon was shade upon him, and the [Radak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14261&st=&pgnum=194) explains that this happened 40 days later when the Sukka dried out and therefore it was not providing shade anymore.

Answer (score 4):

He built a hut to protect himself from the elements while watching, expecting at least *something* bad to happen to Nineveh. Nothing to do with the holiday.